# minivan driver side sliding door only opens 1 foot

Tags: toyota, sienna

2005 Sienna, the driver side sliding door opens but only a foot, feels like it's hitting into something.  The gas door is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I manually pushed on the button inside the gas access door and got it to open that way.  Turns out there's a tiny latch on the bottom rail that wasn't closing right (maybe some dirt got under it) so cleaned out around that, works again.  See also

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GH3jKTWqYPg